# How to decompress lz4 file

Tags: image, file, lz4

I have a folder/file which is with the extension abc.tar.lz4
I want to be able to view the contents of this file but I have been unable to do so. I am using MACOS and I installed lz4 via my terminal using the command:

```
brew install lz4
```

How can I view the contents of this file?

Comment: Try `/usr/local/bin/lz4 -dc < abc.tar.lz4 | tar xvf -`

Comment: Or maybe omit the `<` from above.

Comment: I get this as the output/error @MarkSetchell : abc.tar.lz4: is not a regular file

Comment: Mmm, ok. Try `file abc.tar.lz4` to see what sort of file it is.

Comment: abc.tar.lz4: LZ4 compressed data (v1.4+) @MarkSetchell

Comment: This folder is placed on the desktop folder

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As mentioned by Mark Setchell what worked for me is:

```
 /usr/local/bin/lz4 -dc < abc.tar.lz4 | tar xvf -
```

where:

**/usr/local/bin/lz4** -> *the path where lz4 is installed. Since I used homebrew, it installs packages within /usr/local/bin*

And replace abc.tar.lz4 with the **.tar.lz4** file name.